# handling arguments of the form --argname="value1 value2" in bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I'd like to allow my bash script `foo` to accept arguments as follows:

```
> foo --arg-name="argval1 argval2 ..."
```

such that i can access the argument value in a variable as if i had defined it

```
    ARG_NAME="argval1 argval2 ..."
```

So far I've tried doing `ARG_NAME=${1#*=}` but this only accepts arguments of the form

```
> foo "--arg-name=\"argval1 argval2 ...\""
```

and that's no decent solution.

I'd appreciate a solution that works in pure bash without using a getopts solution.

Comment: have a look at `getopt` and `getopts`. Also, `"$@"` returns an array with all the args inside

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. `ARG_NAME=${1#*=} ` works fine for me. Can you include an example demonstrating that it fails?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, @thatotherguy. Using bash the first call yields `$1 == "--arg-name="`. As a consequence `"" == ${1#*=}` . Btw, I am using $@ in my actual script, but I don't think that relates to my problem, because it splits the input arguments the same way as $0, $1, $2 ...

Answer (score 0):

First, get [getoptlong](http://www.sputnick.fr/scripts/getopts_long.sh)

Then check this demo :

```
#!/bin/bash

# ( long_option ) 0 or no_argument,
# 1 or required_argument, 2 or optional_argument).

Help() {
cat<<HELP
Usage :
    $0 [ --install-modules <liste des modules> ] [-h|--help]
HELP
    exit 0
}

. /PATH/TO/getopts_long.sh

OPTLIND=1
while getopts_long :h opt \
    install-modules 1 \
    help 0 "" "$@"
do
    case "$opt" in
        install-modules)
            echo $OPTLARG
        ;;
        h|help)
            Help; exit 0
        ;;
        :)
           printf >&2 '%s: %s\n' "${0##*/}" "$OPTLERR"
           Help
           exit 1
        ;;
    esac
done
shift "$(($OPTLIND - 1))"
```